# What does "He felt the bed for his glasses..." mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> He felt the bed for his glasses...

This is from Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire. I'm interested to know whether I have understood it right. I feel that it means: "**He used his hands to find his glasses on the bed by placing them at different parts of it.**" Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's pretty much what it means, "He used his hands to feel different parts of the bed in order to find his glasses."  The phrasing is a little odd, however, but perhaps "he felt the bed" is not an uncommon BrE expression.  I would have expected something like:

> He felt **around** the bed ...
>
> He felt **under/beneath** the bed ...

Or possibly (if the glasses were under the blankets):

> He felt **in** the bed ...